# Cannot use getParam to get values from onchange event

Tags: lightning, lightningselect

I have a number of `<lightning:select>` components in an iteration like so:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.data}" var="obj">
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
            {!obj.Name}
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
            <lightning:select name="{!obj.Id}" value="{!obj.Role}" onchange="{!c.changeRole}">
                <option>Primary</option>
                <option>Secondary</option>
                <option>Other</option>
            </lightning:select>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

Each of these deals with a particular record, so when a change is made, I need to know the Id, as well as the new value of the select. My method:

```
changeRole: function(component, event, helper) {
    var val = event.getParam('value');
    val id = event.getParam('name');
    console.log(id+'-->'+val);
}
```

...ends up printing "undefined-->undefined" to the console every time.

I know that the prescribed method of getting these values is to use `component.find('aura-id').get('v.value')`, but that requires my selects to be static, not dynamic. I also know that I've successfully used `getParam` in similar situations in the past.

How can I get the values I need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use `event.getSource()`

```
changeRole: function (component, event, helper) {
   const value = event.getSource().get('v.value');
   const name = event.getSource().get('v.name');
}
```